# How to loop through only the Selected items value in a Placeholder dropdown list-Code Behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-placeholder

aspx

```
<select id="ddColumns" name="ddColumns" runat="server" multiple style="width: 400px;"
    data-placeholder="All" class="chosen-select">
</select>
```

DLL

```
ddColumns.DataSource = AvailableColumns
ddColumns.DataTextField = "ColumnNames"
ddColumns.DataValueField = "ColumnNames"
ddColumns.DataBind()
```

The code that loops through each item in dropdown

```
For Each selection As ListItem In ddColumns.Items
    If selection.Selected Then
        ddGroupBy.Items.Add(selection.Value)
    End If
Next
```

Instead of looping through each item I need to loop through only the selected ones in the Placeholder dropdownlist.

Please advise.

Comment: The problem is that it loops through all the items in the order in which they appear in the dropdown.If I select a value further down in the dropdown and then the first value ,it doesnot adds the first value to ddGroupBY and then the value further down.But I want them in the order of selection.The values in ddGroupBy is passed to a sql statement to group by in the order of selection.

Comment: Thats the problem.It is not doing that.Is there a way to only loop through the selected items like ddcolumns.selecteditem.value something(Just for clarifiaction)

Comment: It's not clear. What means "order of selection"? If you have three items and the user selects first item 2 and then item 1 you want that the items are added to the other ddl in the same order, so first item 2 and then item 1? Is that correct? If so, use a real `DropDownList` , set `AutoPostBack` to `True` and handle it's `SelectedIndexChanged` event. Then you can add always a single `ListItem` to the second ddl, the one which was selected at that time.

Comment: So are yioou saying that it is not possible to loop through selected items in the order of selection in a placeholder?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes thats the idea..I cannot change it to a dropdownlist because I need many other functionalities.I really need a solution for this.If you get any information please let me know.Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a little easier to do this with Javascript:

```
var a1 = selectElem.getElementsByTagName('ddColumns'); 
var a2 = [];
for(var i=0; i<a1.length; i++) {
    if(a1[i].selected)
        //do something;
}
```

Comment: Do you know any way to do this in code behind?Thank You.

Comment: No, I don't believe it is possible.